# $f(f(x))=g(g(x)),f(f(f(x)))=g(g(g(x)))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

> If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials such that
>   $$f(f(x))=g(g(x)), \phantom af(f(f(x)))=g(g(g(x)))$$
>   prove or disprove $f(x)=g(x)$.

My try:
So since $f(f(x))=g(g(x))$, we have
$$g(g(g(x)))=f(f(f(x)))=g(g(f(x)))$$
which doesn't necessarily prove that $f(x)=g(x)$. It seems to be not enough information to prove it, but I don't know how to construct a counterexample. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose this weren't true. Then, we know that the set $\{f(f(x))\mid x\in\mathbb C\}$ must be finite since otherwise, the polynomials would agree upon infinitely many values and hence be equal, as for all $y=f(f(x))$ $$f(y)=f(f(f(x)))=g(g(g(x)))=g(f(f(x)))=g(y)$$

But, the only way that the set can be finite is if $f(f(x))$ is constant, which is only possible if $f$ is constant. This would imply that $f=g$, a contradiction.

So, $f=g$.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to include how you got $f(f(f(x))) = g(f(f(x)))$ (it took me a little while to get it). It's only one extra equality but I think it would still help.

Comment: Do you mean the set $\{f(f(x)) = g(g(x)) | x \in \mathbb{R}\}$?

Comment: @MadhavNakar No, I don't. That set is just $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @DonThousand I don't see how you conclude the equality $f(f(f(x))) = g(f(f(x)))$ directly from $f(f(x)) = g(g(x))$. I see it as $f(f(f(x))) = g(g(g(x))) = g(f(f(x)))$, using both assumptions.

Comment: @Sambo fine, I'll add that. I see what you mean.

Comment: @MadhavNakar Perhaps you were thinking of the set $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = g(x)\}$. Explicitly, if the polynomials aren't equal, then $S$ must be finite. But we know the set $\{f(f(x)) : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is a subset of $S$, so it must be finite as well.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $f$ and $g$ have the same degree and if it is zero then both are constant and clearly the same. From $$f(f(f(x)))=g(f(f(x)))$$ we see that $f$ and $g$ have the same values on a set $S= f(f(\mathbb{C}))$. So unless $f$ is constant $S$ must be infinite and thus $f$ and $g$ are the same.